# Unable to get Mocha and Angular mocks to work in Plunker

Tags: mocha.js, angular-mock, plunker

I am trying to show an example of mocha in plunker but it is giving me angular mocks undefined issues. I tried copy and pasting bower angular mocks to no avail.

```
beforeEach(function(){
  angular.mock.module('plunker');

});
```

Errored code from angular-mocks says window undefined

```
(window.beforeEach || window.setup)(function() {
  annotatedFunctions = [];
  currentSpec = this;
});
```

[Plunker found here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGkMZDfuDh1QPAbh74mc?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move the angular mocks script below the call to `mocha.setup('bdd');` and it works fine.

I've updated your plunk at http://plnkr.co/edit/yH9V6b?p=preview